# Is it possible to configure cloud-init to upload a file from local machine to remote instance while building it?

Tags: cloud-init

I am building remote machine using claud-init  yaml file (#cloud-config).
The Remote machine needs to run PHP app with Postgress database.
Everything works but I couldn't find away to upload my postgress latest.dump to the new server via cloud-init configs.

Dump file sizeis is 16MB.
All other files I'v needed for the app pulled via git or created using the write-files module. But the dump file is too big for that. and also might contain sensitive data.

Comment: If you can expose your database dump at an `http://` or `https://` url, you could add a script to your `cloud-init` configuration to download it and apply it when the system boots. If you don't have other options you could stick it in an AWS S3 bucket and provide appropriate credentials in to your VM via cloud-init.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it seems the way to go.  I was hoping for a way to send/upload the dump directly from my own machine but it seems that cloud-init have no support for direct uploads